# Tensorflow Module Not Found When Using shell_exec()

Tags: php, python, tensorflow, shell-exec, tensorflow-serving

So I have gone through 3 different VMs of Ubunutu messing with things trying to get a shell_exec() command to work from PHP with Tensorflow.

Tensorflow is installed and working properly I can use it all day from the command line. If I run python -V from the PHP file using shell_exec() its the same version I'm using from terminal to run this command:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -W ignore /var/www/html/test/scripts/label_image.py --image /var/www/html/test/tmp/bat.jpg 2>&1
```

I used paths for everything and tried it without running it local from the directory either way does not work in the php shell_exec() call. But yet if I run this from the terminal in SSH it works fine, with or without absolute paths.

I get this error when running it through the PHP script:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/www/html/test/scripts/label_image.py", line 25, in import
>   tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow

I have spent hours messing with this and really cannot figure out why it's not working, please help!!

Running Ubuntu18 with Apache2 LAMP stack.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you found a solution?